# Regex allowing spaces (for a Phone number regex)

Tags: php, regex, phone-number

I have this regex:

```
preg_match("#^([0-9]+)$#", $post['telephone'])
```

who allow only numbers (for a phone number in the French type so 0123456789) but I would like to allow spaces. For example allow this type of string: "01 23 45 67 89".

Can you please help me?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If it is OK to have spaces anywhere in your string then it is simple, just add it to your character class

```
preg_match("#^([0-9 ]+)$#", $post['telephone'])
```

but this will allow 5 spaces in the beginning.

```
^\d{2}(?: ?\d+)*$
```

would be a bit more sophisticated. Starts with two digits, then a optional group starting with an optional space followed by at least 1 digit. this group can be repeated 0 or more times.

This would match

> 01 23 45 67 89
>
> 0123456789
>
> 01234 5679

Answer (score 8):

If you want to have exactly 8 digits, e.g., but still allow for arbitrary number of whitespace characters, the following is great:

`^(?:\s*\d){8}$`

Or, if you want to allow dashes too:

`^(?:\s*-*\s*\d){8}$`

Answer (score 1):

This one strips out anything but digits, spaces and a dash.

```
$input = '0123?> Abc -_#';
$output = preg_replace('#[^0-9- ]#', '', strtolower($input));
echo($output);
```

Do you want to just validate (matches and abort) or cleanse, try and clean up and carry on?

Answer (score 0):

Just had the same issue, if anyone comes across this issue, I've created this regex :

```
(?:((?:\+|00)(?:33|33\s0))|0)\s*[1-9](?:[ ]\d{2}){4}
```

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/aFIwp7/1

It will cover all french options for mobile numbers and non mobile numbers.

Comment: The regex101 link is always a great addition, but you still ought to put the regex in your answer to prevent it from getting removed for being a 'link-only answer'.

Answer (score -1):

How about this?

```
preg_match("/^\d(\s*\d)*$/", $post['telephone'])
```